# Dynamic key in immutability update helper for array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

I have an update function that receives an index along with the event so as to alter the value for that specific item in the array.

How do I get `index` to be evaluated instead of treated as a set key in this scenario? Is it even possible?

```
updateValue: function(index, e) {
  var items = React.addons.update(this.state.items, {
   index: {
     amount: {$set: e.target.value}
   }
  });
  this.setState({
    items: items
  })
}
```

Right now this obviously doesn't work because it's attempting to update `this.state.items['index']['amount']` which is not set, when I want to modify `this.state.items[1]['amount']` for an index of 1.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use [ES6 computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), which would look like this with your `index` variable:

```
updateValue(index, e) {
  var items = React.addons.update(this.state.items, {
    [index]: {
      amount: {$set: e.target.value}
    }
  })
  this.setState({items})
}
```

According to this [ES6 compatability table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#jsx), React's JSX transpiler supports them when its Harmony transforms are enabled, or you could use [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) instead (since [react-tools is being deprecated in favour of Babel](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) anyway).

Failing that, you could use a helper function to create an object with a given named property:

```
function makeProp(prop, value) {
  var obj = {}
  obj[prop] = value
  return obj
}

// ...

updateValue: function(index, e) {
  var items = React.addons.update(this.state.items, makeProp(
    index, {
      amount: {$set: e.target.value}
    }
  ))
  this.setState({items: items})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I am using the [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem and despite enabling the harmony flag as documented and making sure the [computed property transformation is supported](https://github.com/facebook/jstransform/blob/master/visitors/es6-object-computed-property-visitors.js), I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`, so I'll stick to the helper method until they ship it with Babel.

Comment: I'm confused by the helper function example. `this.state.items` is an array, and you are updating it to `{1: { amount: $set: e.target.value } }`. I'm still learning how the update addon works, but seems to me that shouldn't work. Assuming it does work somehow, couldn't he have just done `update(this.state.items[index], { amount: {$set: e.target.value }})`? Does update have some special case for arrays that allows this to work?