# ReactJS - Using .setState to change nested values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to set the state of a specific element (a checkbox) so that I can later pass this data back to a parent component that will in turn update a JSON object. I am able to set the state of higher level elements but I am not understanding how to access the nested values.

How do I use .setState to set the state of a specific element? Such as `this.state.data[0].checked`

I'm attempting to set the state with something like this which would only update `data` at the moment:

```
handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({data: event.target.value}});
  },
```

Comment: could  you share some codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use the [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), and if you are using a numerical / dynamic key, you should look at my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899454/dynamic-key-in-immutability-update-helper-for-array).

Your solution would look something like this:

```
handleChange: function(index, event) {
  var data = React.addons.update(this.state.data, {
   [index]: {
     checked: {$set: event.target.checked}
   }
  });
  this.setState({
    data: data
  })
},
```

Notice the use of `e.target.checked` and not `e.target.value` for checkboxes to get the boolean state and not the value associated with the checkbox.

This is how you'd attach your function with the i index you'd have to set beforehand:

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. I updated your post with a couple of small syntax edits and had to throw in that comma at the end to make SO happy. Thanks!